i got TypeError: UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
I want to create super user just from email and password so it should create super user without username.
I am using custom user model and when i try to create superuser i got this error TypeError: UserManager.create_superuser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'username'
This is my manager.py file
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

This is my models.py
class User(AbstractUser)
    """
    Abstract User of django auth user model.
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, null=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_profile/', blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(blank=True, choices=Department.choices,
                                  max_length=2)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    last_logout = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    view = models.TextField(blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []


from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
import uuid


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The given email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """
    Custom User model where email is the unique identifier instead of username.
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, null=False, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_profile/', blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(blank=True, choices=Department.choices, max_length=2)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    last_logout = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    view = models.TextField(blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email




above things remove error but due to this username is blank but i want email value also set in username
at the end  of my model i have this
def __str__(self):
    return self.get_username()


By using your above solution i can only create one super user after i got error django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_user_username_key"
DETAIL:  Key (username)=() already exists.

You use for class User inheritance class AbstractUser.
Class AbstractUser have required field username.
Override field in class User or fill username in UserManager or don't use inheritance class AbstractUser.
update
To override django user model you need write new AbstractUser without username field you can copy builtin model with changes, and set user model in settings.py.
Django user model override
something like that:
class AbstractUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    Username and password are required. Other fields are optional.
    """

    email = models.EmailField(_("username"))
    first_name = models.CharField(_("first name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_("last name"), max_length=150, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
        _("staff status"),
        default=False,
        help_text=_("Designates whether the user can log into this admin site."),
    )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _("active"),
        default=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Designates whether this user should be treated as active. "
            "Unselect this instead of deleting accounts."
        ),
    )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_("date joined"), default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    EMAIL_FIELD = "email"
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["email"]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("user")
        verbose_name_plural = _("users")
        abstract = True

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.username = self.__class__.objects.normalize_email(self.email)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        """Return the short name for the user."""
        return self.first_name

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """Send an email to this user."""
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)


If not abstractuser then what should i use?

You can use field username as email field like "username = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)", if you want use AbstractUser class.

from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
 
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("The Email must be set"))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):

        extra_fields.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_superuser", True)
        extra_fields.setdefault("is_active", True)

        if extra_fields.get("is_staff") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_staff=True."))
        if extra_fields.get("is_superuser") is not True:
            raise ValueError(_("Superuser must have is_superuser=True."))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)



class AppUser(AbstractUser):

    username = None
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["first_name", "last_name"]
    objects = CustomUserManager()

Try to make username field Nonefield
